# Structure interface breaking

Tags: ee2, structure, ee2-upgrades

I am using structure in my current project and the interface is not displaying correctly. No files have been altered within the addon. Be[image]low you can see how my interface looks. Any Idea what would be causing this?

Comment: had the same issue a few times. do you use the most current versions? if you go into the entries manually, can you place them back in the right order?

Comment: I am using the latest version. Not sure what the issue was exactly. Luckily enough it was quite earlier in the build. I uninstalled structured and then Installed again and it corrected the glitch. The interface would work correctly otherwise unfortunately. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a pretty bad issue like this, and after looking at the DB, I found the problem with lft/lgt. See: http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/debug_mode_for_page_data/

My bug was resolved by fixing duplicates with the debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest version. Not sure what the issue was exactly. Luckily enough it was quite earlier in the build. I uninstalled structured and then Installed again and it corrected the glitch. The interface would work correctly otherwise unfortunately. thanks :)